# Replace an video with an image when the screen is too small

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, mobile

Im working on a website and struggeling with the mobile version for it. My Problem is that i want the video to disappear when the screen is less the 600px and instead of the video it should show a picture with the same width and hight. This is my code for the video.

```
    <div id="video" class="view hm-white-light jarallax"  data-jarallax='{"speed": 0.1}' data-jarallax-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=1Cpj3GdEG1s?start=[60]&end=[180]">
   <div class="full-bg-img">
      <div class="container flex-center">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
               <div class="text-center">
                  <h1 class="Zedextitel" data-wow-delay="0.3s" align="center" style="font-size:100pt; color:white;">TEST</h1>
                  <h5 class="Videotitel" data-wow-delay="0.4s" style="font-size:30pt; color:white;">TEST</h5>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried many Solutions with CSS something like:

```
    @media (max-width: 767px)
   {
    #video
      {
        display:none !important;
      }
}
```

But the Problem with this solution is that the video goes away completly with out any background. Even if i add:

```
background: url(/pictures/test.jpg)no-repeat center top;
```

Nothing appears there where the Video was. This really bothers me and i dont know what i could try out. Maybe some of you guys can help me? I thought maybe something with javascript could help but i never learned it so i dont know where to start with JS.

Comment: On what container are you adding that background?

Comment: In the @media in the #video{}. I tryed it also with the "poster="" " tag but it didnt worked either.

Comment: I don't exactly know what are you doing with all those containers, but keep the video and image containers seperate as shown in my solution and set the initial display of image container to none and when resized to block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your image container is inside your video container, so when you set it to none all of it gets hidden, so keep both of the containers seperate. Take the `image out of your video container`, since you're hiding the entire container when the viewport size is less than 767 px. Initially, set the `display of the full-bg-img to none` and when viewport is resized, display it as block using media query as shown.

```css
.full-bg-img {
  display: none;
  background: url(/pictures/test.jpg)no-repeat center top;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #video {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .full-bg-img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="video" class="view hm-white-light jarallax" data-jarallax='{"speed": 0.1}' data-jarallax-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=1Cpj3GdEG1s?start=[60]&end=[180]">
</div>
<div class="full-bg-img">
  <div class="container flex-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1 class="Zedextitel" data-wow-delay="0.3s" align="center" style="font-size:100pt; color:white;">TEST</h1>
          <h5 class="Videotitel" data-wow-delay="0.4s" style="font-size:30pt; color:white;">TEST</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example to demonstrate you how:

```css
#full-bg {
  display: none;
}
#video video{
    width:100%;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #video {
    display: none;
  }
  #full-bg {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>

<div id="full-bg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-87.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: But the video should run when the screen is bigger then 767px. It should disappear when its less then 767px and show an image.

Comment: @Zedex Yeah, it will. Since, its not hidden by default and is being only hidden when resized below 767px. Use the logic as I posted, keep the video containers and image containers seperate and not inside one other. Then hide the image container outside media query and display it inside media query, whereas hide the video container inside media query.

Comment: @Zedex I've demonstrated another example below the code. Check it out

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i had to had "height:50%;" then it showed up! Thanks for your help i appreciate it! :)